# EJB Performance optimisation between different containers

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, glassfish, ejb

EJB is slower than pure well optimized JDBC but here http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/qotm047.shtml it is said

> " the simple JDBC/EJB comparison assumes that your JDBC is as
>   efficient as the EJB generated JDBC. That is by no means certain, as
>   the container vendors can have specialist developers who are expert in
>   producing optimal SQL."

How do I know the logics of optimization between JBoss, Glassfish, TomEE ? How do I know that it is actually suited to my particular application as generic optimisation is kind of premature optimization : can I check the code generated somehow ? And can I override that optimization if necessary if yes how ?

Comment: You have too many questions here, and TomEE is invalid - I think you mean Tomcat, right?

Comment: Actually, TomEE is 'correct' for this question: http://openejb.apache.org/apache-tomee.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can see the generated sql, and yes, you can generally use your own.  Most Java EE containers use other jpa libraries, like hibernate and eclipselink. These libraries have ways to display the sql they are using. They also have ways of using your own jpql or sql.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I know the logics of optimization between JBoss, Glassfish, TomEE ?

By looking at the generated SQL, and by examining the source code.  Also, by reading the documentation.

> How do I know that it is actually suited to my particular application as generic optimisation is kind of premature optimization

That doesn't make sense.  The "premature optimization" syndrome is when you (the programmer) spend your time in *hand optimizing* the code ... before it has been established that the optimization is needed.  By contrast, the optimization that is being performed by the container is done automatically, and takes ZERO developer time.

> : can I check the code generated somehow ?

Yes.  But how you do it is container specific.  Read the container specific documentation.

> And can I override that optimization if necessary if yes how ?

I think that also depends on the container.

---

Have you noticed that there is a common pattern in this Answer?   It is also worth noting that Tomcat is not an EJB container, and that there's no such thing as "TomcatEE".

Comment: By looking at the generated SQL, and by examining the source code. Also, by reading the documentation: but how if it is generated at runtime ?

Comment: For TomEE I'm refering to this http://openejb.apache.org/apache-tomee.html